# How to get file from documents directory which is in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have audio recorded in iphone app so how can get access to that file

File path where it is stored.

```
NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@_%@_%@.wav", NSHomeDirectory(), theCellData.firstName,theCellData.lasttName,type];
```

Comment: Print your NSLog for path string.

Comment: Your question is not clear ... (and plz add code block around code text). Do you want to access the file from your app or outside your app (like from itunes) ?

Comment: I want to access it in my app in other class and use it to send to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi think you want something like this

```
NSString *filePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.extension"];
```

and elsewhere:

```
-(NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;

}
```

where filepath give the location where file is located in document directory....